# XMLWorker class using iTextSharp to convert HTML text into PDF document

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

Its been told that HTMLWorker is deprecated in favor of XMLWorker. But when I googled around &  I cannot find much help around this class. I am struggling to find the DLL which contains the implementation for this class.

I have looked at the following links:

http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/?source=dlp

While I am still searching for an example which will show me how to convert HTML text into a PDF document using XMLWorker class while utilizing the CSS class, it would be great if someone can please help me on this.

Comment: What do you mean when you say *while keeping the CSS class*? Do you mean you have problems using `CSSResolver`?

Comment: I mean while utilizing the CSS class.

Comment: iTextSharp files live on SourceForce: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/

Comment: (iText and) iTextSharp have moved away from SourceForge and are now on GitHub: http://github.com/itext/itextsharp
Please don't use the SourceForge link any more. If SF gets even worse than it is already, we may cut our ties with SF entirely.

Comment: You have the Example #3 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp/25164258#25164258).