# LoadTagStyle - margin

Tags: c#, itext

I am using iTextSharp to create a PDF file from some HTML content in the CMS. I am trying to format the results as per the webpage, using the following;

```
styles.LoadTagStyle("h2", new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"color","666666"},
        {"size","26pt"},
        {"face","corporatea"}
    });
```

I want to add a bottom margin to my h2 (as they are in the html), but adding does not appear to work;

```
styles.LoadTagStyle("h2", new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"color","666666"},
        {"size","26pt"},
        {"face","corporatea"},
        {"margin-bottom","10pt"} (or 10px),
    });
```

I have tried a number of ways, for example;

```
styles.LoadTagStyle("h2", "style", "font-family:Arial;font-size:22pt;color:red;margin-bottom:10px;font-weight:normal;");
```

But nothing is working, the color, size etc is all working fine, can anyone make any suggestions, am I doing something clearly wrong here?

I am reading HTML in from the CMS;

```
var htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(myhtmlstring), styles);
for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
{
    doc.Add(htmlarraylist[k]);
}
```

Comment: See this for a big overview on [parsing HTML and translating it to PDF syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25164258/231316). Basically, `HTMLWorker` is deprecated, not maintained or supported and only handles the most basic of style attributes and values. If you want real CSS you'll want to switch to `XMLWorker`. If you're stuck with `HTMLWorker`, however, you should only use the [tags, attributes and values that are listed in this file](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/HtmlTags.cs). For colors, include the pound sign, `#FF0000`.

Answer (score 0):

if margin - bottom is not working then i have one idea that you can add one blank Paragraph after h2 tag.

Hope it works for you !!

Comment: The PDF should match the HTML in the CMS exactly, I don't want to add extra p tags in to space elements, I just am not sure if it's simply not supported in iTextSharp or I am doing something wrong

Comment: if you want to give space after your h2 tag then i have suggested one work around idea that you can add blank Paragraph.                Paragraph emptyParagraph = new Paragraph(" "); doc.Add(emptyParagraph);

Comment: I have edited my original post, I am reading the HTML into a list using HTMLWorker.ParseToList, and then outputting them to the document from that list, so your suggestion won't work for me, but thanks anyway

Comment: ok.. when you are reading HTML and writing into DOC to generate PDF you can check that if h2 tag comes then you can add <P> into your documents so you will your PDF looks good.

Comment: ok having played a bit more, i can add the spacing using styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.H2, HtmlTags.AFTER, "10");

Answer (score 0):

```
styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.H2, HtmlTags.AFTER, "10");
```

Comment: It's ok to mark your own answer as the accepted one, if it solved the issue you were facing.