# iTextSharp error Invalid nested tag body found, expected closing tag script

Tags: itext

I am getting the following error when trying to generate PDF after converting a Pie Chart to Image. 
Can someone advise what is wrong in my HTML file?

```
**Additional information: Invalid nested tag body found, expected closing tag script.**
```

The following call in BaseHtmlToPDF.cs raise the exception

```
parser.Parse(reader);
```

The is is my HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Chart</title>

    <link href="https://localhost:44302/Content/report-pdf.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://localhost:44303/Content/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://localhost:44303/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://localhost:44303/Scripts/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://localhost:44303/Scripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://localhost:44303/Scripts/nv.d3.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="reportBody">
        <div id="SummaryChart">
            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="title-con">
                        <h2>IdleTime (Hours)</h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="SummaryChart" style="height:500px">
                            <svg></svg>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <script>

            var values = [];


            var data = [{

                values: values,
                key: 'IdleTime'
            }];



            data[0].values.push({"y": undefined, "x" : '2015/03/01'});
            data[0].values.push({"y": undefined, "x" : '2015/03/22'});
            data[0].values.push({"y": undefined, "x" : '2015/04/20'});
            data[0].values.push({"y": undefined, "x" : '2015/04/21'});
            data[0].values.push({"y": 19.5, "x" : '2015/04/22'});
            data[0].values.push({"y": undefined, "x" : '2015/04/23'});
            data[0].values.push({"y": undefined, "x" : '2015/04/24'});
            data[0].values.push({"y": undefined, "x" : '2015/04/29'});
            data[0].values.push({"y": undefined, "x" : '2015/04/30'});


            init_graphs(data);

            function init_graphs(data) {
                nv.addGraph(function () {
                    var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();
                    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {

                        var dateTimeFormat = 'dd-MMM-yyyy';
                        dateTimeFormat =  dateTimeFormat.replace('dd', '%d');
                        dateTimeFormat =  dateTimeFormat.replace('MMM', '%b');
                        dateTimeFormat =  dateTimeFormat.replace('yyyy', '%Y');
                        return d3.time.format(dateTimeFormat)(new Date(d));
                    });

                    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));
                    chart.showLegend(false)
                    chart.xAxis.axisLabel('Time');
                    chart.yAxis.axisLabel('NPT Hours');
                    chart.showControls(false);
                    chart.margin({ left: 90, top: 90, bottom: 50, right: 20 });
                    chart.transitionDuration(0);

                    var max = 19.5;
                    var scale = calculate(0, !max || max < 10 ? 10 : max, 10);
                    chart.yDomain([scale.niceMin, scale.niceMax]);
                    d3.select('#SummaryChart svg')
                        .datum(data)
                        .call(chart);

                    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

                    return chart;
                });

                function niceNum(range, round) {
                    // exponent of range
                    var exponent;
                    // fractional part of range
                    var fraction;
                    // nice, rounded fraction
                    var niceFraction;
                    exponent = Math.floor(Math.log(range)/Math.LN10);
                    fraction = range / Math.pow(10, exponent);

                    if (round) {
                        if (fraction < 1.5) niceFraction = 1;
                        else if (fraction < 3) niceFraction = 2;
                        else if (fraction < 7) niceFraction = 5;
                        else niceFraction = 10;
                    } else {
                        if (fraction <= 1) niceFraction = 1;
                        else if (fraction <= 2) niceFraction = 2;
                        else if (fraction <= 5) niceFraction = 5;
                        else niceFraction = 10;
                    }
                    return niceFraction * Math.pow(10, exponent);
                }

                function calculate (min, max, maxTicks) {
                    maxTicks = maxTicks ? maxTicks : 10;
                    var range = niceNum(max - min, false);
                    var tickSpacing = niceNum(range / (maxTicks - 1), true);
                    var niceMin = Math.floor(min / tickSpacing) * tickSpacing;
                    var niceMax = Math.ceil(max / tickSpacing) * tickSpacing;
                    var tickValues = [];
                    for (var value = niceMin; value <= niceMax; value += tickSpacing)
                        tickValues.push(value);
                    return { niceMin: niceMin, niceMax: niceMax, tickSpacing: tickSpacing, tickValues: tickValues };
                }
            }
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: iText(Sharp) doesn't interpret JavaScript; you are trying to do something that is impossible with iText(Sharp). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp

Comment: @Bruno, i mistakenly pasted script code in my above question. Anyways, i have edited my question and pasted pure HTML code for which i am getting nested body error.

Comment: Your edit replaced one script-loaded HTML by another. Try an HTML without scripts.

Comment: Or surround your Javascript with HTML comment tags; e.g. <script><!-- ... --></script>