# Convert html page to pdf file using itextsharp version 5.5.5.0

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I want to convert an HTML page to a PDF page. I have a windows application.

I saw many articles but did not find any right solution. I am also facing the images path issue and some other issues like the input string is not of the correct format. Pleas help me to find a solution for that so that I can use it in my windows application.

I am using the following code

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim document As New Document()
    Try
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\SCRA_Resources\SCRA.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        document.Open()
        Dim wc As New WebClient()
        Dim htmlText As String = wc.DownloadString(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\SCRA_Resources\SCRA.html")
        Dim htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StringReader(htmlText), Nothing)
        For k As Integer = 0 To htmlarraylist.Count - 1
            document.Add(DirectCast(htmlarraylist(k), IElement))
        Next
        document.Close()
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

When i run this code i am getting the error Could not find file 'C:\TestProjects\MergePDfs\MergePDfs\bin\Debug\help.gif'.

I am putting these image where my html file is save. But the html worker cut the path two folder before. And also its not taking the CSS fully.

Comment: Any existing code you can share?

Comment: please share what you have tried and the specific areas where you are facing an issue

Comment: This is a great place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp Make sure to use [XML Worker](http://itextpdf.com/product/xml_worker), **NOT** `HTMLWorker`. If you have a problem with paths to images, you'll need to create your own implementation of the `ImageProvider` interface (see [ParseHtmlImagesLinks](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/D09_ParseHtmlImagesLinks) vs [ParseHtmlImagesLinksOops](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/D08_ParseHtmlImagesLinksOops) to compare a working examples vs an *Oops, it doesn't work* example).

Answer (score 0):

Let me go through your code to explain a couple of things.

First get rid of your `Try` and `Catch` and avoid ever using them in the future. Sounds weird, I know. But everything in code is technically "try this" because every line of code can fail. The only reason to ever use the actual `Try` command is if you have a valid `Catch` block that actually does something useful. Logging is one thing. Showing an error message is another, but since you're in VS that's covered already.

Next are these two lines:

```
Dim htmlText As String = wc.DownloadString(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\SCRA_Resources\SCRA.html")
Dim htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StringReader(htmlText), Nothing)
```

The right part of the first line is "get some HTML from a very specific location" and the left part is "and put that into a variable as a string that's totally unaware of the original specific location". Read this a couple of times if it doesn't make sense because it should explain why the second line can't find the images.

Your image links are all relative but relative to what? I know you want it to be your specific folder but you didn't actually specify that in any way. HTML has (or maybe had, I haven't done this in a decade probably) a way to do this via the `base` tag but I don't know if iText supports that. So instead you need to tell iText "when I say relative, I mean relative to this folder".

Before continuing, it is important to understand that you are using a very old, officially obsoleted and no longer supported helper class that lacks many features and will eventually cause you a lot of grief. The `HTMLWorker` class was replaced with the `XMLWorker` class many years ago. Although the `HTMLWorker` class sounds like something that's more appropriate, think of the `XMLWorker` as "XHTML" instead of "XML".

Okay, so if you're stuck using `HTMLWorker`, you can solve this by implementing the `iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.IImageProvider` interface. If you do this and you are using the 5.x series you should hopefully get a bunch of warnings because, as was said above, `HTMLWorker` is officially obsoleted. The `GetImage` method of this interface will be called for every image in your document. Below is a very simple implementation that takes a single parameter for the constructor that specifies what the new location should be. Ideally you should add some error handling (this is a good candidate for a `Try\Catch` because your `Catch` could be to include an explicit "image not found image") and if you have a mixture of absolute and relative images you should check for that, too.

```
Public Class RelativeRootImageProvider
    Implements iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.IImageProvider

    Public Property BasePath As String

    Public Sub New(basePath As String)
        Me.BasePath = basePath
    End Sub

    Public Function GetImage(src As String,
                             attrs As IDictionary(Of String, String),
                             chain As iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.ChainedProperties,
                             doc As IDocListener) As iTextSharp.text.Image Implements iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.IImageProvider.GetImage
        ''//This should also check to see if src is absolute and maybe try getting it first before the below.
        ''//The below could also have a File.Exists() check, too.
        Dim newSrc = System.IO.Path.Combine(BasePath, src)
        Return iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(newSrc)
    End Function
End Class
```

To use this you just need to create a special collection and add it to it:

```
''//Pick a folder
Dim RelativeImageRootPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)

''//Collection of providers
Dim providers As New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Object)()

''//Add our image provider pointed to our specific folder
providers.Add(HTMLWorker.IMG_PROVIDER, New RelativeRootImageProvider(RelativeImageRootPath))
```

And then pass the providers as the third parameter of the `ParseToList` method:

```
Dim htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StringReader(htmlText), Nothing, providers)
```