# iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml not working

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using  iTextSharp version: 5.5.6; iTextSharp XML Worker version: 5.5.6

I got some code from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp/25164258#25164258), but after I run the code, the PDF file will never open

> :The file is damaged and could not be repaired. Local\EWHvxm9t5++
>
> htmltext="\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
>   \r\n       \r\n        \r\n       \r\n         \r\n   \r\n
>    \r\n    Item \r\n    Description\r\n   
>   LotNo\r\n   Revision\r\n   NamePlatSN\r\n
>   DateCreated\r\n   CreatedBy\r\n \r\n   \r\n
>   \r\n    \r\n     100-817412-001\r\n      X500-G02 -
>   ENV DWG            \r\n    15020008\r\n     B
>   \r\n    testing123\r\n     4/9/2015 12:00:00
>   AM\r\n     ULTRATCS\xma\r\n     \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n        \r\n  \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"

The HTML string (better formatted) looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en\" >
<body>




        <table> 

   <tr> 
   <th> Item </th>
   <th> Description</th>
   <th>   LotNo</th>
   <th>Revision</th>
   <th>NamePlatSN</th>
   <th>DateCreated</th>
   <th>CreatedBy</th>

   </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> 100-817412-001</td>
     <td> X500-G02 - ENV DWG            </td>
    <td>15020008</td>
    <td> B      </td>
    <td>testing123</td>
    <td> 4/9/2015 12:00:00 AM</td>
    <td> ULTRATCS\\xma</td>

    </tr>
    </table>



</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code:

```
 protected ActionResult ViewPdf(object model)
        {
            // Create the iTextSharp document.          
            Document doc = new Document();
            byte[] buf;
            // Set the document to write to memory.
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memStream);
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            doc.Open();
            string htmltext = this.RenderActionResultToString(this.View(model));      

               using (var srHtml = new StringReader(htmltext))
                 {
                            //Parse the HTML
                            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
                            //buf  = new byte[memStream.Position];
                            //memStream.Position = 0;
                            //memStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                            buf = memStream.ToArray(); 

                            doc.Close();
                        }       
           // System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\\temp\test.pdf", buf);
            // Send the binary data to the browser.
            return new BinaryContentResult(buf, "application/pdf");
        }       
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: ParseXHtml method is not using for parse HTML code?

Comment: What I need to do is: I have to generate a report. In order to do that, I created a normal razor view, then try to use ParseXHtml to create a PDF report.

Comment: Try calling `doc.Close()` _before_ calling `buf = memStream.ToArray(); `

Comment: OMG! you are genius! After I switch these two statements, it is working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

*(as discovered through the comments)*

You need to call `doc.Close()` before calling `buf = memStream.ToArray();`. This let's iTextSharp know that you are actually done and it should flush any buffers and write the PDF trailer.