# iTextPDF - Unable to convert HTML to PDF

Tags: java, itext

I am building a Java web service application in which I would like to convert the HTML file to PDF and send an email to a particular email address.

**Conversion from XHTML to PDF.**

```
                 try {

                    File outputFile = new File("D:\\Files\\Output_Files\\" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf");
                    OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                    Document document = new Document();
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
                    document.open();
                    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlString.getBytes());
                    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,is);
                    document.close();
                    file.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I have verified `htmlString` and it holds an exact HTML string.

Please review my HTML content [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/JCnT3MpgMsV8qe6Msi6N/)

The issue is that I am receiving the PDF but it does not have any content but an empty page.

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916122/itextsharp-tool-xml-xmlworkerhelper-getinstance-parsexhtml-not-working

Comment: I am not clear . Should I swap document.close(); and file.close(); ?

Comment: I found a related question and I thought it would be beneficial to link it here in case it helps solve your problem

Comment: No. It did not :-(