# Convert live HTML to a PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: html, asp.net, pdf, itext

I want to save a webpage as a PDF using iTextSharp.

The HTML I want to save as a PDF is generated from ASP NET with labels populated via a database. There are also user checked checkboxes.

How can I get the current HTML being displayed in the browser and save it as a PDF on the server side?

Comment: Is this really Classic ASP or is it ASP.NET?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert HTML to PDF using iTextSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Comment: ASP.NET. Added incorrect tag.