# Html to pdf - how can we create a pdf file from html with textbox controls with CSS styles

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

I have a requirement where I need to write my asp.net page information into pdf file with the css styles(inline/style sheet file). While creating pdf we have to make the textboxes to labels with textbox like border and similar for dropdowns, checkboxes. Can you please help us on how to proceed?

Comment: HTML to PDF using iTextSharp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp

Comment: Sudipta, I have been trying iTextSharp. I stuck at the textbox/checkbox controls, i.e. not writing the textboxes to pdf file. Do you have any idea how to implement as I said above?

Comment: What did you try? Try to replace textbox with label.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DynamicPDF Converter for .NET](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/PDF-Conversion-.NET.aspx), it is not a free tool but it can convert several different file types including HTML to PDF. It uses Internet Explorer (IE) to render the HTML and convert that to PDF. The formatting and styles of the resulting PDF will look similar to how your HTML is displayed in the IE’s print preview.

Disclaimer: I work for ceTe Software, the company that develops DynamicPDF libraries.