# Converting dynamic cshtml to pdf using iTextSharp?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pdf-generation, itext

I was using [Rotativa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa) for the conversion of html to pdf. My whole aim was to send receipt as pdf to customers emailid. It was working well locally but when deployed in `GoDaddy Server` its not supported. So I am planning to generate the pdf using `iTextSharp`(Viewers Opinion is also invited).

Code written for the generation of pdf in Rotativa:

```
 public ActionResult GetPdfReceipt(int RegId)
 {
    var actionPDF = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("GetPdfReceipt", new { RegId = regId })
    {
      FileName = "Receipt.pdf"
    };
     //Dynamic student receipt pdf
     var byteArrayDynamic = actionPDF.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);
 }

 public ActionResult GetPdfReceipt(int RegId)
 {
    try
    {
        var _mdlReceiptPdf = new ReceiptPdfVM
        {
                ...
                ...
        };
        return View("Receipts", _mdlReceiptPdf);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View("");
    }
}
```

I have gone through some of the codes for generating pdf using iTextSharp and it was as follows

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=LoginReportPerDay.pdf");
        StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hTWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter);

        GridView1.RenderControl(hTWriter);
        StringReader sReader = new StringReader(sWriter.ToString());
        Document pdf = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(pdf);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdf, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        pdf.Open();
        worker.Parse(sReader);
        pdf.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(pdf);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

How can I use the above code to render dynamically generated Receipt View pdf array bytes.

Comment: Is your question, "How do I get a PDF as a byte array instead of writing directly to `Response` object's stream"? If so, instead of using `HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream` use a `System.IO.MemoryStream` and call `ToArray()` on it when you're done. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25164258/231316) for a sample as well as an explanation on why not to use `HTMLWorker` any more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . My problem is I cannot set value of `example_html` as a static string or path as mentioned the [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp/25164258#25164258).Its is dynamically created at runtime.So how can I parse dynamically generated `view` to `string`.

Comment: Do this help? [Render a view as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/483091/231316)