# ItextSharp prinitng document from URL

Tags: .net, itext

like many people that mess around with iTextSharp, I need to build something with it but I have no clue whatsoever due to the lack of proper documentation. But anyways, I need to print a page (an Invoice) that is dynamically filled on render. I was wondering if there was a way to pass the URL of said page, i.e., `~/invoicedoc.aspx?invoiceid=1` and then get it to render the page, print the pdf with said page's content and finally send it to the user as a `Http.Response`.

Please help because i have looked for tutorials everywhere but apparently not many people have this problem.

Comment: iTextSharp is the .Net port of iText. On their official site you can find [examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples), [documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/classes), [FAQs](http://developers.itextpdf.com/frequently-asked-developer-questions), a free [eBook](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) and even [printed books](http://developers.itextpdf.com/books). Anyway, you are looking for the XML Worker additional library which can turn HTML into PDF commands. I'd [start with this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25164257/231316).

Comment: Thanks man! the links you provided helped me in finding some pretty good solutions :)

Comment: So it's not lack of documentation, but lack of people being able to find the documentation? How can iText Software help to make the existing documentation for iText and iTextSharp easier to find?

Comment: It is lack of documentation, you can't find much directly related to ItextSharp, most of the solutions are on SO comments and answers which are a bit hard to sift through. Basically Itext Software should gather the knowledge in those comments and answers and unify that information on one solid knowledge center instead of widespread bits and pieces. It's my opinion though, give it whatever credit you find worthy