# How do I export my HTML page which is dynamically generated by AngularJs as PDF?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, pdf

I have tested JavaScript library jsPDF for a exporting a complete page to pdf and downloading the same. Wasn't really happy with the format of elements that has an overflow which I have handled through CSS. But seems to get the basic work dome.
Also has some issues if i assign it to onload event. The page gets stuck and browser stops responding.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO].Please take time out for a [tour] and visit the [help]. You might also want to read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert HTML to PDF using iTextSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kendo library seem to do an Ok job for me clientside but you do get some rendering issues now and then.

You will get the best results from a server side rendering library. You can scrape the HTML from the DOM and send it server side to a rendering engine like ABCPDF and the results are usually pretty good.