# itextsharp: How to export DataGridView (Templatefield) to PDF in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, itext, templatefield

So i got this Problem i´m stuck with.
I have a DataGridView which contains the data from an SQL Server. Inside that GridVIew the columns are in templatefield.
How am i able to Export this datagridview to a pdf?

Right now i´m using itextsharp. And i tried many Things (Google search to site 12...). I can´t use this htmlparser / htmlworker.
The best solution would be something like a foreach loop Looking for the values in These templatefields.

The only way Right now is to connect to my SQL database and with a while Statement get all the values from the table. But not the column headers.
I can make a new table for the ColumnName (pdfpcell etc.) but i can´t repeat this table to all pages in my pdf (or i don´t know how?)
Does anyone know a solution for my (stupid) Problem? ^^.

i can´t Show you the Code because i can´t Export to the Internet.

btw: i am using asp.net 4.0, in C#.

Comment: You can't copy-paste from your code-editor to StackOverflow?

Comment: You can try with html to pdf.
For reference can see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp

Comment: thx for your Reply. i found a solution. :D