# Export to PDF using iText not displaying complete data from GridView

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to export my `GridView` to PDF.  When I click the button I can see that the document downloading with around 977KB but when it has finished download and browse to the download folder the file size then is 1KB.

This is the code I am using:

```
protected void ExportToPDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
     "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

I am not sure what is going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert HTML to PDF using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Comment: What do you do `Response.Write(pdfDoc)` for? That's definitively wrong.